# I need help retrieving user input from my code

Tags: c#

I've only been learning C# for about a week, and I have this personal project that I am working on. I am building a program to calculate a salesperson's monthly bonus. At the end of my code, I need to tell the user the total bonus amount and the bonus cannot exceed $230.

My question is, how do I retrieve the user inputs to get a total and how do I set a limit of $230?

Any help will be appreciated.

I tried using more if statements to retrieve what the user already input.

```
Console.WriteLine("What is the total number of items sold?");
int itemsSold = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
int itemBonus = 50;

if (itemsSold > 20)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your items sold bonus is {0} dollars" ,itemBonus);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("You have not sold enough items to recieve the item bonus");

Console.WriteLine("What is the total dollar value of all items sold?");
int bonus1 = 100;
int bonus2 = 200;
int dollarValue = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
double totalEarned1 = (dollarValue * bonus1 + itemBonus);
double totalEarned2 = (dollarValue * bonus2 + itemBonus);
if (dollarValue >= 1000 && dollarValue < 5000)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have recieved a bonus of {0} ", bonus1);
}
else if (dollarValue >= 5000)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have recieved a bonus of {0} ", bonus2  );
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have not recieved a dollar value bonus");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem, I can't make sense out of it! I mean what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refactorize your code. Since if the user did not sell more than 20 items, it is of no use to continue the calculation:

```
Console.WriteLine("What is the total number of items sold?");
int itemsSold = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
int itemBonus = 50;

if (itemsSold > 20)
{
    int bonus1 = 100;
    int bonus2 = 200;

    Console.WriteLine("Your items sold bonus is {0} dollars" ,itemBonus);
    Console.WriteLine("What is the total dollar value of all items sold?");

    int dollarValue = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    double totalEarned1 = (dollarValue * bonus1 + itemBonus);
    double totalEarned2 = (dollarValue * bonus2 + itemBonus);

    totalEarned1 = Math.Max( totalEarned1, 230 );
    totalEarned2 = Math.Max( totalEarned2, 230 );

    if (dollarValue >= 1000 && dollarValue < 5000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have recieved a bonus of {0} ", bonus1);
    }
    else if (dollarValue >= 5000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have recieved a bonus of {0} ", bonus2  );
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have not recieved a dollar value bonus");
    }
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("You have not sold enough items to recieve the item bonus");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow this helped a lot. I can apply this reasoning to other things i'm working on as well.  Thank you!

Comment: If you found this answer useful, you could choose it as the correct answer.